# Exposing a Dokku (or Docker) Container to server IP address

Tags: docker

I'm working with a client that just lost control of their domain name and I'd like to be able to continue working on the site.

Since the domain name is no longer resolving to the Digital Ocean server, I'd like to start accessing the site directly via it's IP address and possibly a random port as well.

I've got a postgres container setup with a randomly generated port number `0.0.0.0:XXXXX` using the postgres plugin, but would like to do the same with the app container.

Comment: And if someone could add a `dokku` tag as well I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to turn off vhost by running the following command:

```
dokku config:set APP NO_VHOST=1
```

Note that in a future dokku version, we may provide better procedure around this

Comment: Works great, thanks! I assume I just remove this config when I want to go back subdomain based apps?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I should add that after removing the `NO_VHOSTS` I also had to rebuild the app to get it to fix the nginx.conf too, but otherwise it was pretty easy, Thanks again.

Comment: I don't argue/question the value of your answer! But please explain the "**we may provide**" ... Eg by adding an appropriate "disclosure"  about any type of link that may exist between you and "dokku" (if such link exists), for those who are not familiar with "dokku". Such disclosure seems to comply with the rules around here also ... and can prevent invalid flagging of this answer ...

Comment: I'm [josegonzalez](https://github.com/josegonzalez), one of the [maintainers of dokku](https://github.com/orgs/dokku/people). Feel free to flag my answer - which is otherwise valid... - if that isn't good enough.